# How to choose the right cables for medium/high voltage applications?

Tags: cables, high-current

After two years, I will graduate as an electrical engineer. My job will require installing bulbs, Washing machines, heaters, refrigerators and air conditioners ... etc. 
I know that each device requires a specific current. My question is: How to determine the diameter or cross section area of a cable that should be used ?
I've googled and found some complicated calculations and complex tables. I would like to know what the easiest way to know the right cable is. I see some electricians can determine the cable immediately when they are asked, and I don't want to take long time in calculations while I'm at work. So, Is there a simple equation or a method to pick the right cable ?
Thanks in advance,

Comment: The criteria listed are not dependent on voltage.

Comment: For the kind of equipment you're talking about, it's more a matter of building code than engineering calculations. Get a copy of your local code or regulations and after you've done a couple of jobs you'll remember the limits for the types of wire you use often.

Comment: Definitelly there is an easy way, but it comes after a deep and complete knowleges and some experience in the electrical science. Electricity it is not a field to play, since humal lifes at least it stakes here.

Comment: Side-note: light-bulbs and washing machines are not 'medium voltage' or 'high voltage' to an electrical power engineer. To a power engineer, "low voltage" is 1,000V, medium voltage is 33,000V, and high voltage is 132,000kV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have previously answered some similar questions: [How do I tell what gauge wire I need?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108144/how-do-i-tell-what-gauge-wire-i-need/108159#108159) and [High voltage cable cross section](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111463/high-voltage-cable-cross-section?rq=1) .

I will expand a bit more, below.

In Australia, we have two relevant standards:

- AS 3000 - Wiring Rules. Covers minimum requirements for a safe
  installation, including that:

  - cables should not melt due to overheating,
  - cables should not catch fire in fault conditions,
  - cables should be large enough to meet a 'fault loop impedance' requirement for safety in case of earth fault, and so on.
- AS 3008 - Selection of Cables. Includes numerous tables and
  calculations for calculating the current-carrying capacity of various
  sizes and types of cables, under various installation conditions.

In some applications there are short-cuts. The final sub-circuits of commercial and domestic wiring, i.e. power points, washing machines, etc. will usually be 2.5mm² copper. Lighting circuits will usually be 1.5mm². And so on. You will learn these shortcuts as you work.

2.5mm² is good for about 20 amps under **most** installation conditions. But not **all** installation conditions. Part of your work as an engineer is to determine when the 'short-cut' will do, and when the 'short-cut' is inappropriate and detailed calculations are required.

Things to consider in cable selection:

- Current requirement of the load (amps)
- Voltage drop - for long cable runs this is just as much a concern as the current-carrying capacity.
- Ambient conditions - hot surroundings or poor ventilation decrease the capacity of the cable, so you need a bigger cable for the same current.
- Cable fault withstand capacity - the ability of the cable to withstand the temperature rise in case of a short-circuit. If the cable is too small, it will catch fire before the fuse/circuit breaker operates.
- Cable insulation material - EPR cables have a higher rating than XLPE, which in turn has a higher rating than PVC. So if you use EPR, your cable can be  smaller than the equivalent in PVC.
- Physical installation considerations - sometimes better to use two smaller cables than one big cable, if you have to make a sharp bend.
- Spacing between cables - if installing multiple cables in the same run, they heat each other up, which decreases their capacity, so the cables have to be bigger.
- Special requirements - metallic screening to prevent radiated electromagnetic interference? De-rating due to non-sinusoidal load current i.e. switching power supply? Full size neutral or half size neutral? And so on.

When you become a professional engineer, and you are responsible for cable selection, you will be introduced to the relevant standards in your country, such as AS 3000 and AS 3008.

**Follow them.** In my country they are the *minimum* requirement. *No short-cuts*. No short-cuts *even if the electrician says it's OK*.

Usually the electrician knows what they are talking about (more than you, the engineer), but if you are signing off on an electrical design then it is *your* name on the dotted line, not the electrician's. If it blows up and burns something down, the electrician will be nowhere to be found - the lawyers will come after *you*.